# CSS how to show only 1 image in slider

Tags: html, css, image, slider

I've got 4 images in my slider.
If I open my website I'm able to see all of them. How can I hide 3 of them? They only slide in when click on arrow?

```
<div id="content">
            <div class="container">
            <div class="slider_wrapper">
                <ul id="image_slider">
                    <li><img src="images/slider-1.jpg"></li>
                    <li><img src="images/slider-2.jpg"></li>
                    <li><img src="images/slider-3.jpg"></li>
                    <li><img src="images/slider-4.jpg"></li>
                </ul>                   
                <span class="nvgt" id="prev"></span>
                <span class="nvgt" id="next"></span>
            </div>
            </div>


@media only screen
and (max-width : 700px) {
/* Styles */
   .slider_wrapper {
       max-height: 150px;
   }
   #image_slider{
   max-width: 100%;
   }
   #image_slider img{
       width:100%;
   }

}

@media only screen
and (min-width : 1280px) {
/* Styles */
   .slider_wrapper {
       max-height: 150px;

   }
   #image_slider{
   max-width: 100%;
   }
   #image_slider img{
       width:100%;
   }

}

@media only screen
and (max-width : 1280px) {
/* Styles */
   .slider_wrapper {
       max-height: 150px;

   }
   #image_slider{
   max-width: 100%;
   }
   #image_slider img{
       width:100%;
   }

}

@media only screen
and (max-width : 1024px) {
/* Styles */
   .slider_wrapper {
       max-height: 150px;

   }
   #image_slider{
   max-width: 100%;
   }
   #image_slider img{
       width:100%;
   }

}
.slider_wrapper{
    max-width: auto;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 85%;
}
#image_slider{
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
    /*Chrom default padding for ul is 40px */
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}
#image_slider li{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
.nvgt{
    position:absolute;
    top: 150px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 30px;
    opacity: 0.6;
}
.nvgt:hover{
    opacity: 0.9;
}
#prev{
    background: #000 url('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/65639888/image/prev.png') no-repeat center;
    left: 0px;
}
#next{
    background: #000 url('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/65639888/image/next.png') no-repeat center;
    right: 0px;
}
```

I know it is possible, but since I've made it responsive, it's not working anymore.

Comment: Can you include the entire code?  Js files references are missing.

Comment: some good slider code links http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/parallaxslider/index.htm  and 
http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex4/simplegallery.htm